# Mask SSN in spring data rest response body

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest, masking

I am creating a rest service using Spring REST. In few services like Identification, I need to Mask SSN in response. (without usingJSON ignore or JsonProperty)

If clients send the SSN in the request body, the response body for SSN should be masked as shown below. (example, Postman requests body and response)
SSN should be masked as xxx-xxxx-1235 in the response body.

Is there any way in spring data rest to achieve this? Or any common solution that could be applied on all entities/controller when ResponseEntity is returned (like Interceptor)?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the jackson `@JsonGetter` could be used for this case.

```
@JsonGetter("ssn")
public String getCensoredSsn() {
  return Something.CensorSsn(ssn);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this two ways. First was to override the get method for the required field and mask it right there. Other way was through combined use of creating CustomSerializer and using @JsonSerialize(using=CustomSerialzier) annotations at a class level.

public class CustomSerializer extends StdSerializer